# Gray questions in the iOS app

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

First time when I opened a new (1.6.4) version of the iOS app I saw that posts tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) were gray:

> [image: gray]

I thought this is done for posts with ignored tags, but I don't have favorite nor ignored tags on site.

Now all questions in the list displayed as in early versions of the app. Problem has gone. What's this have been?

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: I've never used the app, just a wild guess, is it questions you read already maybe?

Comment: @JasonC Nope. As I say in the post, now all displayed as was in old versions. I.e. I can't unread these posts back, if I already read them.